# Chrome web app manifest: differences between display types

Tags: html, google-chrome, manifest

When creating a web app manifest for Chrome, you can specify your `display` as `fullscreen`, `standalone`, `minimal-ui` or `browser`

What are the differences between `fullscreen` and `standalone` and when should I use which?  They seem very similar to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you use `standalone` it looks like a native app. When you use `fullscreen` there is no system status bar - the app covers whole screen.

What you want most often is `standalone`. Choose `fullscreen` if you have a specific use-case, such as gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Valid options for display are `fullscreen`, `standalone`, `minimal-ui` and `browser` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display.

In order to show the **Add to Home Screen Prompt**, display must be set to must be one of: `fullscreen`, `standalone`, or `minimal-ui`, see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

`browser` display option is like leaving the field empty.